# Using column name when calling a function (cutpointr)

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform a evaluation of optimal cutpoints on several pairs of variables/classes, using the `cutpointr` package (https://rdrr.io/cran/cutpointr/man/cutpointr.html). The documentations states that the syntax of the command is `cutpointr(data, x, class)`, with the former two being `variable names`.

My dataframe looks like the following, with every ID having several variables A,B,... and corresponding binary classes for each variable.

```
ID   A   B   A_Class   B_Class
1    7   5     1        0
2    3   2     0        0
3    6   3     0        1
```

I now want to perform the `cutpointr` operation for each of these pairs. I tried implementing a `for`-loop.

```
for (col in 2:3) {
  cutpoint <- cutpointr(df, colnames(df[col]), colnames(df[col+2]))
  summary(cutpoint)
}
```

This lead to the error `Error: Can't convert a call to a string`.

When typing out the variable names like `cutpointr(df, A, A_Class)` there's no problem. Could someone point out what mistake I'm making here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try using `get()`.  so in your second line`  cutpointr(df, get(colnames(df[col])), get(colnames(df[col+2])))`

Comment: Leads to same error `Error: Can't convert a call to a string` unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes that R supplies when you use the loop to identify the functions.  `cutpointr` looks like it uses tidy evaluation from `rlang`.  Adding `!!` in front of the column names will remove the quotes.

```
library(cutpointr)

## create your example data
df = as.data.frame(cbind(ID = c(1, 2, 3), 
      A = c(7,3, 6),
      B = c(5, 2, 3),
      A_Class = c(1, 0, 0),
      B_class = c(0,0,1)
      )
)

for (col in 2:3) {
      cutpoint <- cutpointr(df, 
                            !!colnames(df[col]), 
                            !!colnames(df[col+2])
      )
      summary(cutpoint)
}
```

This is similar to many of the tools in dplyr and ggplot, more details can be found at https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the solution and the further resources to read through!